# Selecting an element by class, then moving it

Tags: javascript, html

I need to select a certain div by it's classname.

After selecting it, I need to move it up 100 pixels.

Here is what I've tried so far:

**HTML**

```
<div  style="z-index:101;  position: absolute; 
left: 0px; top: 300px; width: 20px; height:450px;
padding: 0px; border: 0px;" class="wrapper" >Content</div>
```

**JS**

```
var class = document.getElementByClassName("wrapper");
var div = class[0];
div.style.top = '100px';
```

Not sure if I'm understanding NodeLists correctly.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/159oaxj0/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** You are missing an `s` in `getElementsByClassName()` ;

**2.** You used `class` as a variable name, but it is a reserved word. Just name it something else.

**3.** To move it up, change the `.style.top` property (300-100 = 200px).

**Fixed code:**

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper");
var div = wrapper[0];
div.style.top = '200px';
```

```html
<div  style="z-index:101;  position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 300px; width: 20px; height:450px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;" class="wrapper" >Content</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

## Why did it not work?

The token class is reserved and can not be used as variable name.
Secondly you made a typo in getElementsByClassName().

## Solution

We can use document.querySelector() instead and omit the array, since it always provides the first match, which works in your case.

```
document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.top = '100px';
```

To move it up 100px from its initial position use

```
var tE = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
tE.style.top = Math.max(parseInt(tE.style.top) - 100, 0).toString() + 'px';
```